# Exchange Managed API: Get Resources List of an appointment

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am creating a utility to get sync room calendar with my application. 
They way i do is by calling syncfolderitems function for the room I want to sync.

Issue: 
Since a User creates an Appointment and we are syncing room calendar thus we are not able to fetch value for  Resources property. After doing some research I found that there is an extended property that can be used to find all attendees (Rooms are also attendees) of appointment. 
Extended property was "PidLidAllAttendeesString".

Issue with this property is that it returns all the attendees of an appointment (Sendable and Unsendable both).
**Is there any property that contains only Sendable attendees data ?**

Answer (score 0):

Based on [[MS-OXPROPS]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433490(v=EXCHG.80).aspx), PidLidToAttendeesString "Contains a list of all of the sendable attendees who are also required attendees." Downloading the PDF of [MS-OXPROPS] and searching on "sendable" or "resource" might yield some other options too. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have already tried PidLidToAttendeesString and this property contains nothing. Its empty string.